# Google Analytics API access token expires after ~60 Secs. How to refresh token with code?

Tags: php, curl, google-analytics, access-token

Google Analytics API access token expires after ~60 Secs.

API URL
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A199721694&start-date=30daysAgo&end-date=yesterday&metrics=ga%3AuniquePageviews&dimensions=ga%3ApageTitle&sort=-ga%3AuniquePageviews&max-results=4&access_token=ya29.ImGbB1J__QZm322Tt2ig2Q6jPWovnKUGn2IU9nRpFSJF1NxLED9sdmUihLxa-dJCGNp9xXph-L8LECyNnsuqzeKvxNDDoXYmTj2L9aLBUJZFHnxUEbUcJg9c46SdQ6hAnDTz

How to refresh token everytime I need to hit this API using PHP cURL?

[image]

I am using this PHP cURL code to hit this API

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A199721694&start-date=30daysAgo&end-date=yesterday&metrics=ga%3AuniquePageviews&dimensions=ga%3ApageTitle&sort=-ga%3AuniquePageviews&max-results=4&access_token=ya29.ImGbB1J__QZm322Tt2ig2Q6jPWovnKUGn2IU9nRpFSJF1NxLED9sdmUihLxa-dJCGNp9xXph-L8LECyNnsuqzeKvxNDDoXYmTj2L9aLBUJZFHnxUEbUcJg9c46SdQ6hAnDTz",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Accept: */*",
    "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Connection: keep-alive",
    "Host: www.googleapis.com",
    "Postman-Token: 099c6ed7-97a7-4e00-94ad-599d3775a723,8dde7ea7-9878-44a2-a532-b718a97973de",
    "User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.17.1",
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Comment: You need a refresh token in order to refresh an accesss token.  When you request access of your user. ask for offline access and you will get a refresh token back you can then use that to request a new access token. You should look into the google php client library rather than making all these calls manually.  I can give you an example with that but not doing it manually with curl.

Comment: Instead of getting access token from query explorer, you should get it from [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) flow or [service account credentials](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php).